# How can I read JSON data from a Sequelize search?

Tags: json, express, sequelize.js

I am developing a handlebars app,

```js
router.get('/findBehavior/:student_id', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("---> req.params.student_id :" + JSON.stringify(req.params.student_id));

    const student = await Student.findByPk(req.params.student_id,{
        include: Behavior,
    });

    console.log("---> student :" + JSON.stringify(student));
    res.render('profile', {student, session: req.session});
});
```

but I have trouble reading this json data that comes into the profile.handlebars:

```js
{
  "student_id": 1,
  "student_name": "Martina Hodson",
  "student_grade": 9,
  "Behaviors": [
    {
      "behavior_id": 1,
      "behavior_name": "No Problems",
      "StudentBehavior": {
        "student_id": 1,
        "behavior_id": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying this code, but it is not working...

```js
{{student.Behaviors.[0].['behavior_id']}}
```

I get a response of

```js
[object SequelizeInstance:Behavior]
```

How can I get the student's name and the student's behaviors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the way I was trying to read the JSON.

It was that the object that comes in response of the search needs to be 'cleaned' before being passed to the handlebars page.

I used this code to make the object plain:

```js
const student = dbStudentData.get({plain: true});
```

Yo can see how it appears surrounded by the rest of the code:

```js
router.get('/findBehavior/:student_id', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("---> req.params.student_id :" + JSON.stringify(req.params.student_id));

    const dbStudentData = await Student.findByPk(req.params.student_id, {
        include: Behavior,
    });

    // HERE --------------------------------------------------------
    const student = dbStudentData.get({plain: true});
    
    console.log("---> student :" + JSON.stringify(student));
    res.render('profile', {student, session: req.session});
});
```

Since it was only one row of data, It wasn't needed a map function to make plain whole set of data when there is more than one row.